# How to find the period of a combined trigonometry function, such as $y=\cos(2x) + \sin(5x)$?

Tags: functions, trigonometry

May I know how to find the period of function such as this?
$$y=\cos(2x) + \sin(5x)$$

Is it true that we just need to find the lowest common multiple of both functions' period, so that we could find the period of this function? If it is, why is that so? What's the mechanism behind this?

Thank you so much for you guys' replies.

Comment: You could first notice that if a function has (minimum) period $T_0$, then it also has period $nT_0$, with $n \in Bbb N$...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose that the function $y$ reaches its initial phase at the point $x=x_1$. Now, for the function $y$ to reach the initial phase, both $\cos(2x)$ and $\sin(5x)$ both must be, individually, at their initial phases as well.

Thus, $x_1$ is the smallest number, at which both the functions $\cos(2x)$ and $\sin(5x)$ have completed integer number of periods. Now it's easy to see that $x_1$ must be the $\text{lcm}$ of those individual periods, that is, the point where both $\sin$ and $\cos$ have returned to their initial phases.

For your case, the period of $\cos(2x)$ is $\pi$ and of $\sin(5x)$ is $2\pi /5$. The $\text{lcm}$ is $2\pi$, which is the period of $y$.

Comment: Thank you very much, may I know whether it is true for other functions that have are periodic? such tan(x)

Comment: You're welcome. Yes, you can use the same procedure for them. But keep in mind that the period of $\tan(Ax)=\dfrac{\pi}{A} $ for $A>0$.

Comment: @HenryCai be careful when generalizing. Take e.g. $\sin^2 x$ and $\cos^2 x$ that individually have period $\pi$...

Comment: @dfnu sure, thank you very much, so sir, you indicate that the period might not solely dependent on the coefficient of the x inside the trig function, right?

Comment: @HenryCai not only that. But also that the sum might not have *minimum* period given by the l.c.m. of the original periods. In my example the sum is in fact a constant.

Comment: @dfnu Thank you for your sharing, that really surprises me.

Answer (score 2):

We know that if $y(x+T)=y(x)$ for some $T\in R^{+}$ then $y(x)$ is periodic with one of its period as $T$.
$$ $$
Period of $Cos(2x)$ is $T_1=\frac{2π}{2}=π$ and that of $Sin(5x)$ is $T_2=\frac{2π}{5}$ 
$$. $$
Hence $T=LCM(T_1,T_2)=LCM(π,\frac{2π}{5})$
$$=2π$$

Comment: Thank you very much, sir.